# node.js i18n like django

Tags: django, node.js, internationalization

Any node.js module can generate i18n files like django does?

I have check several node.js i18n module, it just do something ilke get/set things, but nothing about generate

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your looking for, but:

- .po files can be generated with: https://github.com/andris9/node-gettext
- or you could use http://i18next.com (comes with backend for .po files, converter from json to .po and vice versa, translation ui, ...)

Answer (score -3):

Err node.js is a serverside javascript environment meant for serving? i18n should probably be part of webframeworks build on node, like uhh express?

Comment: There's really no need to be condescending.